# Bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\binom{\mathbb{N}}{2}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $\binom{\mathbb{N}}{2}$ be the set of $2$-tuples of $\mathbb{N}$
>
> Can someone give me an explicit bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\binom{\mathbb{N}}{2}$ ?

Comment: $1\mapsto(1,1), 2\mapsto (1,2), 3\mapsto (2,1), 4\mapsto(1,3), 5\mapsto(2,2), 6\mapsto(3,1), ...$; (do you include $0$ in $\mathbb N$?)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner to be fair, we might choose to skip $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ as well as treat $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ the same etc... so the exact same bijection used between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N^2$ might not work, but clearly the same principles can be used.  The notation $\binom{A}{n}$ is often in reference to the $n$-element subsets (*repetition not allowed and order doesn't matter*) of $A$.

Comment: I don't include $0$ but what if $(1,2) = (2,1)$? Could it be something like $(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(1,4),(2,4),(3,4),(4,4),(1,5),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5),(5,5),(1,6)$? But what is the formula $f(n)$?

Comment: @user100101212 skip elements of the form $(n,n)$ if you don't allow them., Otherwise your pattern is perfectly good.  Now... consider the relation to the triangle numbers and the second larger entry of each tuple.

Comment: You say "what if $(1,2)=(2,1)$", but that is counterfactual: $(1,2) \ne (2,1)$ because [$(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematical_Proof_and_the_Principles_of_Mathematics/Sets/Pairs#Ordered_pairs)

Comment: @JMoravitz:  your point about not including $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ in $\binom {\mathbb N }2$ is well-taken, but then I wouldn't call elements of $\binom{ \mathbb N} 2$ $2$-tuples since [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Properties) says a tuple may contain multiple instances of the same element -- is there a word better than $2$-tuples?  perhaps subsets of $\mathbb N$ with $2$ elements?

Comment: @LeeMosher I don't want to put words into the OP's mouth, however the notation $\binom{A}{2}$ to denote the set of two-element subsets of $A$ is common.  For instance appearing in Stanley's [Topics in Algebraic Combinatorics](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/algcomb/algcomb.pdf) (*see page 6*) as well as in his more elementary texts.  I expect that the OP is just using incorrect terminology and incorrectly including the pairs of the form $(n,n)$.

Comment: The ordered pairs coming from $\Bbb N$ is actually denoted $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ or just $\Bbb N^2$. It’s called a Cartesian product, and it’s really common notation.

Comment: Sorry $\binom{\mathbb{N}}{2}$ is meant to denote 2-sets of $\mathbb{N}$, with elements unordered and distinct $(n,n)$ is not an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed way of ordering them is perfectly fine: $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\},\{1,5\},\{2,5\},\dots$

$n\mapsto \{b_n,c_n\}$ where $b_n$ follows http://oeis.org/A002260 and $c_n$ follows http://oeis.org/A003057

Using one of the example formulas for each, we have for instance:

$n\mapsto \left\{\left\lfloor\sqrt{2(n - 1)} + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor + 1,\left\lceil\dfrac{\sqrt{8n - 7} + 1}{2}\right\rceil\right\}$

Answer (score 0):

*Below I assume $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$, blasphemous though that be.  :P*

---

JMoravitz's answer works, but it's worth noting that there's a general trick for getting a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and some set $S$ from a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $T$ for a "too large" $T$: we can **erase redundancies**.

The value is that this often gives us an easier way to convince ourselves that a bijection exists: we can try to replace the set we care about with a combinatorially simpler set.

The general theorem here is the following:

> Suppose $S$ is infinite, $T$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, and there is a partial surjection $T\rightarrow S$ *(that is, a surjection from some $T_0\subseteq T$ to $S$)*. Then there is a bijection between $S$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

I'll treat the specific case we're looking at here; the general proof is basically identical.

(Incidentally, this same idea is more generally useful for producing *well-orderings* of sets.)

---

Here we have the situation where $S$ is the set of two-element sets of natural numbers and $T$ is the set of ordered pairs of natural numbers. We have a natural partial function $p:T\rightarrow S$ given by sending each ordered pair to its underlying set if that underly set has two elements, and being undefined on ordered pairs of the form $(n,n)$, and we also have a bijection $f:T\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ (say, the Cantor pairing function).

We now whip up a function $S\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ by "picking first representatives:" specifically, we set $$\hat{f}(x)=\min\{f(y): p(y)=x\}.$$ For example, under the usual pairing function we have $\langle 1,2\rangle\mapsto 2$ and $\langle 2,1\rangle\mapsto 3$, so in the corresponding $\hat{}$-map $\{1,2\}$ would map to $\min\{2,3\}=2$.

Now that doesn't *quite* work since the resulting $\hat{f}$ will **not** be a bijection, but merely an injection. To get a genuine bijection we use a further trick, namely the usual "collapsing" construction: given an injection $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ for $X$ infinite, the map $$g^*: X\rightarrow\mathbb{N}: x\mapsto\vert\{y\in X: g(y)\le g(x)\}\vert$$ is a bijection.

Putting this all together, **given a bijection $f:T\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ our desired bijection $S\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ using the notation above is just $(\hat{f})^*$**.